# Setting the product description in the shopping cart

Tags: kentico

I am trying to write code to add an item to the shopping cart.

I have been able to set the price of a product  using

```
cartItem.CartItemPrice = price;
```

how can I set the description that displays?

I have looked at the ShoppingCartInfoProvider but I cant figure out what method to use

Comment: It depends on what you are displaying , what field is being read in the transformation that displays the description?

Comment: How do i find the transformation that displays the description?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my webpart I set cartItem.CartItemText to the description I wanted.

I also edited  GetSKUName  in CMSModles\Ecommerce\ShoppingCart\ShoppingCartContent.ascx.cs to return itemText